# Retrieve the Firestore document id after creation

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I need to get and save the document Id from a newly created document. How do I return this id from the Future or how do I add the docRef.id to the client provider?

```
  Future<void> saveNewClient(client) async {
    try {
      DocumentReference docRef = await _db.collection('client').add(client);
      client.updateClientId(docRef.id);  <<<< CLIENT PROVIDER
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return;
  }
```

This code does not throw an error but it never reaches the client.updateClientId(docRef.id) line. The save works so I should be able to get the docRef.id.

Why is this line being skipped?

**UPDATE:**
Now that I am getting the document id back from the saveNewClient function how do I use the variable to add the id to the client provider? Here is the code:

```
Future<String?> clientId =
          firestoreService.saveNewClient(toMap(newClient));
      ref.read(clientNotifierProvider.notifier).updateClientId(clientId);
```

Since clientId is a future I need to wait for it to be populated. How do I do this?
Thanks

Comment: The _db.collection('client').add(client); might be taking too much time?
Or you can try _db.collection('client').add(client).then((doc){
client.updateClientId(docRef.id);
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this depending your preference or use case

```
 Future<String?> saveNewClient(client) async {
    FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    try {

      /// You can generate a document id before the create operate
      String id = _db.collection("client").doc().id;

      /// pass the generated id to the doc reference and set it
      /// .toMap() -> Assuming your client isn't of type map
      await _db.collection('client').doc(id).set(client.toMap());
      /// upon success return the id
      return id;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      /// or return null if the operation failed
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

After creating a document, you can retrieve its document ID from the DocumentReference object returned by the add() method.

```
Future<void> createDocument() async {

FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

DocumentReference docRef =
  await firestore.collection('YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME').add(YOUR_MAP).then(
(docRef) {
  print('${docRef.id}');
},
 );}
```

Comment: This is help full.